# linq　副問い合わせとmax値の取得について

Tags: c#, linq

お世話になります。
こちらのSQLをlinqに変換したいのですがなかなかうまく行きません。
お手数ですが、ご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
SELECT 　　 id
           ,kaisu
           ,henkou
           ,furigana 
           ,sex
           ,nengo
           ,birthday
           ,idno
  FROM tableA AS A,
  (
  SELECT id as Bid
      ,MAX(kaisu) as Bkaisu
  FROM tableA as B
  GROUP BY Bid
  ) as B
  where A.id = B.Bid and A.kaisu = B.Bkaisu
order by A.id
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

グループ化クエリーの実現方法が分からないということでしょうか。

```
SELECT id as Bid
     , MAX(kaisu) as Bkaisu
  FROM tableA as B
 GROUP BY Bid
```

このようなクエリーは`GroupBy`および`Select`拡張メソッドを組み合わせて実現します。

```
var b = tableA
            .GroupBy(r => r.id)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Bid = g.Key,
                BKaisu = g.Max(r => r.kaisu)
            });
```

このようにあらかじめクエリーを作成しておいて、変数`b`に対して通常のテーブルのように内部結合を行えば副問い合わせを実現できます。

Comment: #pgrhoさん　ありがとうございます。うまく取得することができました。